# dbpedia extract JSON

Tags: html, json, dbpedia

http://dbpedia.org/resource/Los_Angeles
You can request this data programmatically in many formats by using the appropriate header in your HTTP request.
For example "Accept: application/json" will get you the results in JSON.
1. How do I go about retrieving the JSON
2. Since I have to filter only
a class="uri" href="http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#label"
for around 100 links on my page. What is the best way around it

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can retrieve the JSON without having to create special headers by simpy requesting

- http://dbpedia.org/data/Los_Angeles.json

If you're only interested in the `rdfs:label`s of the entity, you might query the endpoint by using a template request URL:

```
http://dbpedia.org/sparql?default-graph-uri=http%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org&query=select*%7Bdbr%3ALos_Angeles+rdfs%3Alabel+%3Flabel%7D&format=json
```

which corresponds to the query

```
select*{dbpedia:Los_Angeles rdfs:label ?label}
```

[SPARQL results](http://dbpedia.org/sparql?default-graph-uri=http://dbpedia.org&query=select*%7Bdbpedia:Los_Angeles%20rdfs:label%20?label%7D&format=text/html&timeout=30000&debug=on)

which generates the JSON:

```json
{ "head": { "link": [], "vars": ["label"] },
  "results": { "distinct": false, "ordered": true, "bindings": [
    { "label": { "type": "literal", "xml:lang": "uk", "value": "\u041B\u043E\u0441-\u0410\u043D\u0434\u0436\u0435\u043B\u0435\u0441" }},
    { "label": { "type": "literal", "xml:lang": "vi", "value": "Los Angeles" }},
    { "label": { "type": "literal", "xml:lang": "zh", "value": "\u6D1B\u6749\u77F6" }},
    { "label": { "type": "literal", "xml:lang": "ca", "value": "Los Angeles" }},
    { "label": { "type": "literal", "xml:lang": "cs", "value": "Los Angeles" }},
    { "label": { "type": "literal", "xml:lang": "de", "value": "Los Angeles" }},
    { "label": { "type": "literal", "xml:lang": "en", "value": "Los Angeles" }} ] } }
```

Comment: what is the difference between: http://dbpedia.org/data/Los_Angeles.json and http://dbpedia.org/data/Los_Angeles.jsond and http://dbpedia.org/data/Los_Angeles.jsod ?

Comment: @tunedconsulting If you look at the bottom of [http://dbpedia.org/page/Los_Angeles](http://dbpedia.org/page/Los_Angeles), you'll see that `Los_Angeles.json` is the JSON serialization of the RDF, that `Los_Angeles.jsod` is the OData in JSON.  `Los_Angeles.jsond` appears to be the same as `Los_Angeles.json`.  The links on the bottom of that page include two other JSON-based representations, too.

Comment: this answer is now outdated, could someone update the url please? thanks

Comment: @divmermarlav I'm not sure which URL you mean.  The one for the data for LA works, for instance. If you suggest an appropriate edit, I'd happily approve, though.

Comment: Sorry, the url is for "SPARQL results". It gives error: `Virtuoso 37000 Error SP030: SPARQL compiler, line 3: Undefined namespace prefix at 'dbpedia' before 'rdfs:label'

SPARQL query:
define sql:big-data-const 0 
#output-format:text/html
define sql:signal-void-variables 1 define input:default-graph-uri <http://dbpedia.org> select*{dbpedia:Los_Angeles rdfs:label ?label}`

Comment: @divmermarlav yes, db Pedia changed their predefined namespaces a while ago in a non- backwards compatible way.  I think the dbpedia prefix would now be dbr.

Comment: Is there some quicker way to get just the abstract?