# Getting JSON/Dictionary of all properties in DBPedia for a page/resource from Wikipedia Infobox

Tags: sparql, wikipedia, ontology, dbpedia, infobox

I'm trying to get a representation of the infobox of articles on Wikipedia in a Python project.  I had tried using the Wikipedia API, but the data it outputs is dirty, so I'm trying to move to DBpedia.  I need to be able to query by page name, and receive a dictionary of the property names and their values for that page.
For example, for the query for [London](http://dbpedia.org/page/London), the returned dictionary would contain:

```
{dbpedia-owl:PopulatedPlace/areaMetro : 8382.0,
 dbpedia-owl:PopulatedPlace/areaTotal : 1572.0
 .....
 dbpedia-owl:populationDensity : 5285.0
 .....
}
```

etc., and from this I would be able to read all the keys that were in the Infobox.  I did try using the SPARQL query of

```
describe <http://dbpedia.org/resource/London>
```

but that returned tonnes of unnecessary data &emdash; the full set of triplets associated with London &emdash; which is many orders of magnitude more than I need.

How can I write a query to just get the infobox properties, as above?

Comment: possible duplicate of [dbpedia extract JSON](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17755229/dbpedia-extract-json)

Comment: If that duplicate doesn't work for you, do you have a way of identifying which predicates you *do* want?  If you can enumerate them, this isn't too hard, but I don't know that there's any way to automatically determine which properties correspond to fields for a certain infobox.

Comment: @JoshuaTaylor the issue is that that returns much more data than necessary - the entire set of triplets if I am correct, with information on them.  I'll double check in the morning and update the question if necessary.

Comment: I guess one approach would to be to only take properties with a given prefix, in which case the kind of filtering in [Exclude results from DBpedia SPARQL query based on URI prefix](http://stackoverflow.com/q/19044871/1281433), [filter out certain properties from sparql query result](http://stackoverflow.com/q/21984461/1281433) may help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might be able to get what you want by selecting properties and objects where the property IRI begins with something you're interested in (e.g., **http://dbpedia.org/ontology/**). You could use a query like the following.  (It takes advantage of the fact that a prefix by itself, e.g., **dbpedia-owl:**, is still a legal IRI, and you can use **str** on it. You could also just use the string **http://dbpedia.org/ontology/**

```sql
select ?p ?o where {
  dbpedia:London ?p ?o
  filter strstarts(str(?p),str(dbpedia-owl:))
}
```

[SPARQL results (HTML Table)](https://dbpedia.org/sparql?default-graph-uri=http%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org&query=select%20%3Fp%20%3Fo%20where%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20values%20%3Fs%20%7B%20dbr%3ALondon%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20dbr%3ALondon%20%3Fp%20%3Fo%0D%0A%20%20filter%20strstarts%28str%28%3Fp%29%2Cstr%28dbo%3A%29%29%0D%0A%7D&format=application%2Fsparql-results%2Bjson&timeout=30000&debug=on)
[SPARQL results (JSON)](https://dbpedia.org/sparql?default-graph-uri=http%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org&query=select%20%3Fp%20%3Fo%20where%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20values%20%3Fs%20%7B%20dbr%3ALondon%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20dbr%3ALondon%20%3Fp%20%3Fo%0D%0A%20%20filter%20strstarts%28str%28%3Fp%29%2Cstr%28dbo%3A%29%29%0D%0A%7D&format=application%2Fsparql-results%2Bjson&timeout=30000&debug=on)

The JSON results aren't quite in the format you're looking for, but are like this:

```
{ "head": { "link": [], "vars": ["p", "o"] },
  "results": { "distinct": false, "ordered": true, "bindings": [
    { "p": { "type": "uri", "value": "http://dbpedia.org/ontology/wikiPageExternalLink" }   , "o": { "type": "uri", "value": "http://mapoflondon.uvic.ca/" }},
    { "p": { "type": "uri", "value": "http://dbpedia.org/ontology/wikiPageExternalLink" }   , "o": { "type": "uri", "value": "http://www.british-history.ac.uk/place.aspx?region=1" }},
    { "p": { "type": "uri", "value": "http://dbpedia.org/ontology/wikiPageExternalLink" }   , "o": { "type": "uri", "value": "http://www.london.gov.uk/" }},
    { "p": { "type": "uri", "value": "http://dbpedia.org/ontology/wikiPageExternalLink" }   , "o": { "type": "uri", "value": "http://www.museumoflondon.org.uk/" }},
    { "p": { "type": "uri", "value": "http://dbpedia.org/ontology/wikiPageExternalLink" }   , "o": { "type": "uri", "value": "http://www.tfl.gov.uk/" }},
    { "p": { "type": "uri", "value": "http://dbpedia.org/ontology/wikiPageExternalLink" }   , "o": { "type": "uri", "value": "http://www.visitlondon.com/" }},
    { "p": { "type": "uri", "value": "http://dbpedia.org/ontology/wikiPageExternalLink" }   , "o": { "type": "uri", "value": "https://london.gov.uk/" }},
    { "p": { "type": "uri", "value": "http://dbpedia.org/ontology/wikiPageExternalLink" }   , "o": { "type": "uri", "value": "http://www.britishpathe.com/workspace.php?id=2449&delete_record=75105/" }},
    { "p": { "type": "uri", "value": "http://dbpedia.org/ontology/thumbnail" }  , "o": { "type": "uri", "value": "http://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/Special:FilePath/Greater_London_collage_2013.png?width=300" }},
...
```

That sort of makes sense though, because there's not necessarily a *unique* value for each property, so a Python **dict** as in the question probably isn't the best result format (but it'd be easy to create one where multiple values are put into a list).

Also note that the properties that begin with **dbpedia-owl:** are actually the DBpedia Ontology properties, which have much cleaner data than the raw infobox values, for which properties beginning with **dbpprop:** are used.  You can read more about the different datasets at [4.3. Infobox Data](http://wiki.dbpedia.org/Datasets#h434-10). A query for the raw properties would be pretty much the same though:

```sql
select ?p ?o where {
  dbpedia:London ?p ?o
  filter strstarts(str(?p),str(dbpprop:))
}
```

[SPARQL Results (HTML Table)](https://dbpedia.org/sparql?default-graph-uri=http%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org&query=select%20%3Fp%20%3Fo%20where%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20values%20%3Fs%20%7B%20dbr%3ALondon%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20dbr%3ALondon%20%3Fp%20%3Fo%0D%0A%20%20filter%20strstarts%28str%28%3Fp%29%2Cstr%28dbp%3A%29%29%0D%0A%7D&format=text%2Fhtml&timeout=30000&debug=on)

Comment: This certainly goes some way - thanks. But I am just noticing from the actual http://dbpedia.org/page/London, some information is abstracted to triples from the Infobox (linked content).  For example, on the wikipedia page (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/London), the infobox has a pairing of `{Mayor : Boris Johnson}`, (where Boris Johnson is a string and link) but in DBPedia this is lost - it becomes simply a list of Leaders (ontology/leaderName).  If I was specifically looking for 'Mayor of London', how would I go about that from this returned information?

Comment: @SamHeather DBpedia doesn't preserve Wikipedia information exactly;  it data *based* on it.  The infobox fields get mapped to DBpedia ontology properties.  If you don't see it somewhere in [http://dbpedia.org/page/London](http://dbpedia.org/page/London), then you probably can't get it, unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

To Get Entire **data of Page in JSON Format** you can also use below method:

Suppose you want JSON data of Taj_Mahal and you have link :

> http://dbpedia.org/resource/Taj_Mahal

Now you have to change this URL by replacing **/resource/** with **/data/** and add **.json** extension in the end of URL. As given Below:

> http://dbpedia.org/data/Taj_Mahal.json

You will get all DBpedia page Matched data with 'Taj_Mahal' in JSON.
Now you have to Expand this 'http://dbpedia.org/resource/Taj_Mahal' in JSON to get only data related to that page.